# Retornar um botão ao seu estado original após o 'popup de download'

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

No meu projeto Java Web há um botão de exportar uma lista para um arquivo CSV que, quando clicado, apresenta a mensagem de *'Por favor, aguarde'* por alguns segundos para, em seguida, retornar ao seu estado original e permitir novas exportações.

Acontece que, em algumas circunstâncias, o processamento desse arquivo CSV pode tomar mais tempo que o timeout definido no javascript, levando o usuário a pensar que a sua solicitação não foi processada e fazendo com que muitas vezes ele clique novamente no botão de exportar, gerando um novo processamento num ciclo infernal.

Eu gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de condicionar o retorno do estado original do botão ao popup de download do arquivo CSV, de modo que o usuário não consiga fazer nova solicitação até que a atual seja efetivamente processada.

Segue abaixo o html do botão:

```
<td id="export" class="textoMaior"><img class="botao" src="${seta}" />&nbsp; 
    <a class="link" onclick="exportar();">
        <fmt:message key="relatorio.exportar" />
    </a>
</td>
```

E o código javascript:

```
function exportar() {
    var msg = document.getElementById("export").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("export").innerHTML="<fmt:message key='relatorio.exportar.aguarde'/>";

    var token = new Date().getTime();
    var t = document.forms.relatorioForm.target;
    document.forms.relatorioForm.elements['total'].value='${listTO.total}';
    document.forms.relatorioForm.elements['downloadToken'].value=token;
    document.forms.relatorioForm.action="<c:url value='/relatorio/transacao/exportar.se'/>";
    document.forms.relatorioForm.submit();
    if (!window.navigator.cookieEnabled) {
        $("#lista").hide(); 
        document.getElementById("export").innerHTML = msg;
    }
    document.forms.relatorioForm.action="<c:url value='/relatorio/transacao/listar.se'/>";
    document.forms.relatorioForm.target=t;
    setTimeout(function retornaBotaoExportar() {
        document.getElementById("export").innerHTML="<td id='export' class='textoMaior'><img class='botao'src='${seta}' />&nbsp; <a class='link' onclick='exportar();'><fmt:message key='relatorio.transacao.exportar' /></a></td>";
    }, 8000);
}
```

Comment: Só um detalhe: no innerHTML do setTimeout vc está colocando outra td dentro da td original, ficando assim uma td dentro da outra com o mesmo id.

Comment: Outra coisa: o que tem no target do form?

Comment: Não tenho certeza se vc está abordando o problema da forma certa, não faz muito sentido rodar um timeout para fazer algo desse tipo, sugiro que vc abra o csv em uma outra pagina . window.open('url do csv')

Answer (score 0):

Tem como tu transformar em um ajax e mudar o estado do botão no callback

```
function retornaBotaoExportar() {
    //Seu codigo
}
$.ajax({type:'GET', 
        cache: false,
        url: rquestURL, 
        data:params, 
        success: function(response) {
            retornaBotaoExportar();
        });
```